# Is it safe to delete the contents of lost+found?

Tags: linux

My XFS went through a failure, which I recovered from using `xfs_repair -L`. As a result, several of my files were corrupted and my lost+found directory had many files/directories created in it which are in the several hundreds of GB (my production system is in the order of TB's)

I have everything backed up, and have restored what was needed. Is it safe to delete the contents of lost+found? Does the OS somehow use it to reference some of my files?

Comment: The contents of the Lost+Found directory are for files that have lost their names in some capacity due to corruption. Since recovering them implies that we need a place to put them, they get stuffed into lost+found with unique names. They will not be linked to anything in this state, and nothing will be using them. Best to recover from backup as you did, as finding out where these files are supposed to belong and what their names are supposed to be is a job for your worst enemy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is safe to delete it. `lost+found` is for the corrupted files, and when they were sorted, it may be deleted. It will be recreated by OS if kind of those files come around again.